# SharePoint List - Modifying center alignment always changes vertical alignment to top

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, json-formatting, column-formatting

I am trying to use JSON formatting to center align the values in a SharePoint List. Whenever I apply the JSON column formatting, it also aligns the values to the top. Even when I then specify that I want the values to remain in the middle, it still aligns them to the top. How do I make it so the vertical alignment stays as the default? I ONLY want to change it to horizontal center alignment.

For reference, this is in a calculated column resulting in a number with no decimal places.

Here is the code.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "display": "table-cell",
    "text-align": "center",
    "vertical-align": "middle"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the following style property to the div element to horizontal center alignment the number:

```
 {
      "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "@currentField",
      "style": {
       "display": "flex",
    "justify-content": "center",
    "align-items": "center"
       }
    }
```

This should center the calculated column resulting in a number with no decimal places both horizontally and vertically:
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you.